# How do I find out if a tuple contains a type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I want to create a compile-time heterogenous container of *unique* types from some sequence of non-unique types. In order to do this I need to iterate over the source type (some kind of `tuple`) and check whether each type already exists in my "unique" tuple.

My question is: **How can I check whether a tuple (or a `boost::fusion` container) contains a type?**

I'm open to using either the STL or `boost`.

Comment: Which version of C++?

Comment: @Deduplicator If it's not specified we shall assume C++11.

Comment: If you are already using `boost` why not use the MPL? This would be a trivial task.

Comment: @Deduplicator yeah I'm using C++11. I assumed the `c++` tag just refers to the current version?

Comment: @pmr, if this can be solved with a "trivial task" I'm all ears!

Comment: I think you are looking more for a TMP version of `std::unique`, rather than finding out if a tuple contains a type.

Comment: @quant: Ah no, not quite. It just means C++, not an old dinosaur. And the current version is C++14 now!

Comment: @quant Either use an `mpl::set` or use a combination of `mpl::sort` and `mpl::unique`.

Comment: @Deduplicator oh right, forgot about that! Well I've added the appropriate dinosaur tag.

Comment: For clarification: Do you really want to test whether the tuple-type already contains the type, or do you want a tuple-type which adds the type if it does not already contain it?

Comment: @Deduplicator well both, but I wanted to keep the question as concise as possible so I'm just asking how to _check_ whether the tuple contains a type.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct has_type;

template <typename T>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<>> : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<U, Ts...>> : has_type<T, std::tuple<Ts...>> {};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<T, Ts...>> : std::true_type {};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c06aef716fdccadb)

And an additional alias, if the trait itself should *be* `std::true_type` *or* `std::false_type` :

```
template <typename T, typename Tuple>
using tuple_contains_type = typename has_type<T, Tuple>::type;
```

Comment: I can't understand how it works... Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: This is very clever! I don't think I'd ever have thought of this. Thanks :)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: it recursively strips off the head-type of tuple (leaving only its tail), until either the new head is same as `T` (then it eventually inherits from `true_type` stopping recursion), or the tuple has no more types (then it ends up with inheritance from `false_type`). Note there are specialized cases for `<T, tuple<T, ...>>` (`T` is same as head `T`) and `<T, tuple<U, ...>>` (`T` is different than head `U`). This is very similar to the way the `tuple` is defined itself.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: That is, `tuple<T, Ts...>` privately inherits from `tuple<Ts...>`

Comment: Good answer, but your constant should probably be a bool value. In c++17 : 
`template <class T, class Tuple>`
`inline constexpr bool tuple_contains_v = has_type<T, Tuple>::value;`

Answer (score 28):

In C++17 you can do it like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct has_type;

template <typename T, typename... Us>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<Us...>> : std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Us>...> {};
```

In C++11 you have to roll your own `or` / `disjunction`. Here's a full C++11 version, with tests:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Conds>
struct or_ : std::false_type {};

template<typename Cond, typename... Conds>
struct or_<Cond, Conds...> : std::conditional<Cond::value, std::true_type, or_<Conds...>>::type
{};

/*
// C++17 version:
template<class... B>
using or_ = std::disjunction<B...>;
*/  

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct has_type;

template <typename T, typename... Us>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<Us...>> : or_<std::is_same<T, Us>...> {};

// Tests
static_assert(has_type<int, std::tuple<>>::value == false, "test");
static_assert(has_type<int, std::tuple<int>>::value == true, "test");
static_assert(has_type<int, std::tuple<float>>::value == false, "test");
static_assert(has_type<int, std::tuple<float, int>>::value == true, "test");
static_assert(has_type<int, std::tuple<int, float>>::value == true, "test");
static_assert(has_type<int, std::tuple<char, float, int>>::value == true, "test");
static_assert(has_type<int, std::tuple<char, float, bool>>::value == false, "test");
static_assert(has_type<const int, std::tuple<int>>::value == false, "test"); // we're using is_same so cv matters
static_assert(has_type<int, std::tuple<const int>>::value == false, "test"); // we're using is_same so cv matters
```

Comment: for pythonists, it's not `or_`, it is `any`

Answer (score 9):

C++17 and up solution using [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
template<typename U, typename... T>
constexpr bool contains(std::tuple<T...>) {
    return (std::is_same_v<U, T> || ...);
}

assert( contains<int   >(std::declval<std::tuple<int, float>>()));
assert( contains<float >(std::declval<std::tuple<int, float>>()));
assert(!contains<double>(std::declval<std::tuple<int, float>>()));

//// In case std::declval ever becomes constexpr, the following should work as well:
// template<typename U, typename Tuple>
// constexpr inline bool contains_v = contains<U>(std::declval<Tuple>());
```

Comment: This gives errors:

constexpr inline bool tupleHasTypeV = tupleHasType<U>(std::declval(Tuple));

error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

constexpr inline bool tupleHasTypeV = tupleHasType<U>(std::declval<Tuple>());
 error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘decltype (__declval<_Tp>(0)) std::declval() [with _Tp = std::tuple<float, myType>; decltype (__declval<_Tp>(0)) = std::tuple<float, myType>&&]’

Comment: @Nuclear It should be `std::declval<Tuple>()`, I updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Xcode (clang) shows error on the last line `Constexpr variable 'contains_v<int, std::tuple<>>' must be initialized by a constant expression`

Comment: @fnc12 You're right - appearently std::declval isn't constexpr unfortunately. I'm sure it worked for me at some point - maybe the implementation of declval was non-standard. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 8):

I actually needed something like this for a project. This was my solution:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
    struct null { };
}

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct tuple_contains;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct tuple_contains<T, std::tuple<Ts...>> :
  std::integral_constant<
    bool,
    !std::is_same<
      std::tuple<typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, Ts>::value, detail::null, Ts>::type...>,
      std::tuple<Ts...>
    >::value
  >
{ };
```

The main advantage of this method is that it's one instantiation, no recursion required.

Comment: I am not able to get this to compile when I try to use it. Clang complains that tuple_contains is declared but not defined. Would you mind providing example calling code?

Comment: std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<tuple_contains<int, std::tuple<char, std::string, int>>::value<<'\n';

Answer (score 8):

Because nobody posted it, I'm adding one more solution based on the bool trick I've learned about here on SO:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<tuple>

template<bool...>
struct check {};

template<typename U, typename... T>
constexpr bool contains(std::tuple<T...>) {
    return not std::is_same<
        check<false, std::is_same<U, T>::value...>,
        check<std::is_same<U, T>::value..., false>
    >::value;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(contains<int>(std::tuple<int, char, double>{}), "!");
    static_assert(contains<char>(std::tuple<int, char, double>{}), "!");
    static_assert(contains<double>(std::tuple<int, char, double>{}), "!");
    static_assert(not contains<float>(std::tuple<int, char, double>{}), "!");
    static_assert(not contains<void>(std::tuple<int, char, double>{}), "!");
}
```

In terms of compile-time performance it's slower than the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25958302/4987285), but it's worth to mention it.

---

In C++14 it would be even easier to write. The standard template offers already all what you need to do that in the `<utility>` header:

```
template<typename U, typename... T>
constexpr auto contains(std::tuple<T...>) {
    return not std::is_same<
        std::integer_sequence<bool, false, std::is_same<U, T>::value...>,
        std::integer_sequence<bool, std::is_same<U, T>::value..., false>
    >::value;
}
```

This is not far conceptually from what `std::get` does (available since C++14 for types), but note that the latter fails to compile if the type `U` is present more than once in `T...`.
If it fits with your requirements mostly depends on the actual problem.

Comment: This is IMO the cleanest (most readable) C++14 solution by far. It is only outshined by the use of folding expression in @Benno Straub 's C++17 answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version that does not recursively instantiate the template to check for a matching type. Instead it uses SFINAE with indices-based meta-programming:

```c++
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t... Indices>
struct index_sequence {
    typedef index_sequence<Indices..., sizeof...(Indices)> next;
};

template <std::size_t Start>
struct make_index_sequence {
    typedef typename make_index_sequence<Start - 1>::type::next type;
};

template <>
struct make_index_sequence<0> {
    typedef index_sequence<> type;
};

template <int n>
using make_index_sequence_t = typename make_index_sequence<n>::type;

template <typename Value, typename Sequence>
struct lookup;

template <typename Value, std::size_t... index>
struct lookup<Value, index_sequence<index...>>
{
private:
    struct null;

    template <typename... Args>
    static std::false_type
    apply(std::conditional_t<std::is_convertible<Args, Value>::value, null, Args>...);

    template <typename...>
    static std::true_type apply(...);

    template <typename... Args>
    static auto apply_helper(Args&&...) ->
    decltype(apply<std::remove_reference_t<Args>...>(std::declval<Args>()...));
public:
    template <typename Tuple>
    using value = decltype(
        apply_helper(
            std::declval<
                typename std::tuple_element<index, Tuple>::type
            >()...
        )
    );
};

template <typename Value, typename Tuple>
using has_type = decltype(
    typename lookup<Value,
                    make_index_sequence_t<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>
    >::template value<Tuple>{}
);
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69a42406b873520a)

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for it, here is a `boost::mpl` version:

```
#include <boost/mpl/unique.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/sort.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp>

using namespace boost;

template<typename Seq>
struct unique_concat : 
  mpl::unique<typename mpl::sort<Seq, is_same<mpl::_1,mpl::_2>>::type, 
              is_same<mpl::_1,mpl::_2>> {};

template<typename T>
struct print;

int main()
{
  typedef mpl::vector<int, float, float, char, int, double, int> input;
  print<unique_concat<input>::type> asdf;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Building with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-long-long -o tpl_b tuple_boost.cpp` yields an error: `tuple_boost.cpp:19:37: error: aggregate ‘print<boost::mpl::v_item<double, boost::mpl::v_item<char, boost::mpl::v_item<float, boost::mpl::v_item<int, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, 0>, 0>, 0>, 0> > asdf’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined` The specific error: `print<unique_concat<input>::type> asdf;`

Comment: I apologize, the version info is `gcc 4.9.1-1` and `boost 1.55.0-6`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is intended. It is an easy way to see the type name.

Comment: why sort+unique ? there is already `mpl::has_key`. isn't it what OP wants ?