# Checking if a tuple contains element of a certain type

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to learn c++ template metaprogramming by implementing some functions. I know the solution to this specific problem has been provided on stackoverflow, what I'm interested in is *understanding why this solution doesn't work*. Here's the code:

```
template < std::size_t... Ns , typename... Ts >
auto tail_impl( std::index_sequence<Ns...> , std::tuple<Ts...> t )
{
   return  std::make_tuple( std::get<Ns+1u>(t)... );
}

template <class F, class... R >
tuple<R...> tail( std::tuple<F,R...> t )
{
   return  tail_impl( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(R)>() , t );
}


template<class X, class F, class... R>
constexpr bool check_for_type(tuple<F,R...> t) {
    if constexpr(is_same<F,X>::value) {
        return true;
    } 
    return check_for_type<X>(tail(t));
}


template<class X>
constexpr bool check_for_type(tuple<> t) {
    return false;
}


int main( int argc, const char *argv) {
    auto t2 = make_tuple(4,"qw", 6.5);
    double f = check_for_type<double>(t2);
    return 0;
}
```

This template is supposed to check if a tuple contains an element of a certain type, but compiling it gives the following error:

```
> clang++ t.cpp -std=c++17
t.cpp:45:12: error: call to function 'check_for_type' that is neither visible in the
      template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
    return check_for_type<X>(tail(t));
           ^
t.cpp:45:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'check_for_type<double, double>' requested here
t.cpp:45:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'check_for_type<double, const char *, double>' requested here
t.cpp:66:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'check_for_type<double, int, const char *, double>' requested here
    double f = check_for_type<double>(t2);
               ^
t.cpp:58:16: note: 'check_for_type' should be declared prior to the call site
constexpr bool check_for_type(tuple<> t) {
               ^
1 error generated.
```

What's wrong with this piece of code?

Comment: @Justin `tail` takes a tuple and returns another one which is input without the first element. I'll edit the code to contain `tail` definition.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using c++17 in your code, I thought it would make sense to point out that there are a lot of new tools to avoid having to make these kind of recursive templates.

You could condense the whole thing to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T1, typename... T2>
constexpr bool check_for_type(std::tuple<T2...>) {
    return std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T1, T2>...>;
}

int main() {
    std::tuple<int, char, bool> tup;
    std::cout << check_for_type<char>(tup) << '\n';
    std::cout << check_for_type<float>(tup) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If `std::disjunction` gets no parameters it defaults to false, so passing an empty tuple is also covered here.

Comment: This answers (in the best possible way IMHO) this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958259/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-tuple-contains-a-typem but it does not belong here, as the OP is asking specifically why their code does not work.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> template<class X, class F, class... R>
> constexpr bool check_for_type(tuple<F,R...> t) {
>     if constexpr(is_same<F,X>::value) {
>         return true;
>     } 
>     return check_for_type<X>(tail(t));
> }
> ```

You are calling `check_for_type<X>(...)` before it is declared. Helpfully, your error message states:

> ```
> t.cpp:58:16: note: 'check_for_type' should be declared prior to the call site
> constexpr bool check_for_type(tuple<> t) {
> ```

Once you do that, the code [compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/x6zR2e):

```
// Put this function first
template<class X>
constexpr bool check_for_type(tuple<> t) {
    return false;
}

template<class X, class F, class... R>
constexpr bool check_for_type(tuple<F,R...> t) {
    if constexpr(is_same<F,X>::value) {
        return true;
    }
    // Right here, the compiler looks up `check_for_type` and doesn't find
    // an overload that can be called with just one explicit type parameter.
    return check_for_type<X>(tail(t));
}
```