# How can I store template types to be used for allocation later?

Tags: c++, reflection, c++14

I'm trying to write an `EntityType` class that can receive and store a variable number of `Component` types.

```
struct Health { int amount; }
struct Position { float x, y; }

EntityType entityType = new EntityType<Health, Position>();
```

I will then use this `EntityType` class later as a blueprint for allocating tightly packed memory for the components.

```
EntityManager.BatchCreate(3, entityType);
// Result: Health | Health | Health | Position | Position | Position
```

Creating a class template with multiple parameters is easy enough, but:

1. How do I store the types to be used as a allocation blueprint later?
2. Can I query what types are in the EntityType?

My first thought for storage was tuples, but I'm not sure. Those take the actual value of the types passed in, and not the type themselves. Can I work with `typeid`'s somehow?

I'm basically trying to replicate in C++ What Unity is doing in C# with [EntityArchetype](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/EntityComponentSystemSamples/blob/master/Documentation/reference/entity_archetype.md), which I believe is using reflection.

Comment: Are the components (`Health` and `Position`) and the size (`3`) both known at compile time?

Comment: Not exactly. The component types are, but the size (how many) is not. Components might be added/removed at run-time (during loading of a scene, or during gameplay), but no new component types would be created at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How do I store the types to be used as a allocation blueprint later?

Since you know the types of the components at compile time, you can use a type alias like this:

```
template<class... Components>
struct Entities {
  /* ... to be implemented ... */
};

using HealthsPositions = Entities<Health, Position>;
```

> 2. Can I query what types are in the EntityType?

Yes, and this is also known at compile time. It seems that there is no helper in the `std` namespace for testing if a type is contained in a typelist (see the diversity of answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958259/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-tuple-contains-a-type)). So here is just another way to solve this *template-metaprogramming* task in C++14:

```
template<class Component, class EntitiesCs>
struct IsComponentOf;

template<class Component, class... Cs>
struct IsComponentOf<Component, Entities<Cs...>> {// partial specialization
  static constexpr bool value_() {
    bool ret = false;
    for(bool is_same : {std::is_same<Component, Cs>{}()...}) {
      ret |= is_same;
    }
    return ret;
// C++17 version with fold expression:
//     return (... || std::is_same<Component, Cs>{});
  }

  static constexpr bool value = value_();
  constexpr operator bool() const { return value; }
};

static_assert(IsComponentOf<Health, HealthsPositions>{}, "");
static_assert(IsComponentOf<Position, HealthsPositions>{}, "");
static_assert(not IsComponentOf<int, HealthsPositions>{}, "");
```

> Can I work with typeid's somehow?

Yes, but that is an alternate approach to what I described above: The above works at compile time. The [`typeid` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) comes from the world of run-time type information (RTTI). Unfortunately, the [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) can not be used at compile time.

> I will then use this EntityType class later as a blueprint for allocating tightly packed memory for the components.
>
> ```
> EntityManager.BatchCreate(3, entityType);
> // Result: Health | Health | Health | Position | Position | Position
> ```

If you really want the components to be closely packed and if you want to be able to resize the "container", then I do not see a simple solution. In the ideal case the `HealthsPositions` store, e.g.,

- a pointer-like member to the memory where the first `Health` component starts,
- a `std::size_t` (or whatever) member that stores the number of components per type, and
- a `std::size_t` (or whatever) member that stores the capacity of components per type.

That ideal case requires some custom memory management (including alignment considerations).

However, a good starting point may be this **alternative simple design**:

```
#include <cstddef>

#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

struct Health { int amount; };
struct Position { float x; float y; };

template<class C0, class... Cs>
struct Entities {
  std::tuple<
    std::vector<C0>, std::vector<Cs>...
  > components;

  Entities(std::size_t size)
    : components{size, (0*sizeof(Cs) + size)...}
  {}
};

template<class Component, class... Cs>
constexpr std::vector<Component>& get(Entities<Cs...>& e) {
  using ComponentVector = std::vector<Component>;
  return std::get<ComponentVector>(e.components);
}

template<class Component, class... Cs>
constexpr const std::vector<Component>& get(const Entities<Cs...>& e) {
  using ComponentVector = std::vector<Component>;
  return std::get<ComponentVector>(e.components);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using HealthsPositions = Entities<Health, Position>;

constexpr std::size_t expected_size =
  sizeof(std::vector<Health>) + sizeof(std::vector<Position>);

static_assert(sizeof(HealthsPositions) == expected_size, "");

int main() {
  std::size_t entity_count = 7;
  HealthsPositions hps(entity_count);

  get<Health>(hps).at(2).amount = 40;
  get<Position>(hps).at(5) = Position{3.5f, 8.4f};

  std::cout << "health address and value:\n";
  for(auto&& h : get<Health>(hps)) {
    std::cout << &h << "\t" << h.amount << "\n";
  }

  std::cout << "position address and value:\n";
  for(auto&& p : get<Position>(hps)) {
    std::cout << &p << "\t" << p.x << "\t" << p.y << "\n";
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
health address and value:
0x55adba092eb0  0
0x55adba092eb4  0
0x55adba092eb8  40
0x55adba092ebc  0
0x55adba092ec0  0
0x55adba092ec4  0
0x55adba092ec8  0
position address and value:
0x55adba092e70  0   0
0x55adba092e78  0   0
0x55adba092e80  0   0
0x55adba092e88  0   0
0x55adba092e90  0   0
0x55adba092e98  3.5 8.4
0x55adba092ea0  0   0
```