# How to restrict userdefined template types based on a condition

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

```
template<typename VarTypes>
class CMyClass
{
   // do something
};
```

currently the code accepts multiple VarTypes Type1, Type2 irrespective of any condition (example compiler option).

I have to like to restrict VarTypes based on the conditions. any experience?

Comment: How are those options reaching the code? As `#define`s? Are you using C++20?

Comment: yes we have defines for the options like #if defined(VARIANT1). C++14

Answer (score 3):

I would keep it simple and just use `static_assert`, e.g.:

```
template<typename T>
class CMyClass
{
#if defined(VARIANT1)
    static_assert (std::is_same <T, std::string>::value ||
                   std::is_same <T, std::vector <int>>::value, "Type not allowed");
#elif defined(VARIANT2)
    ...
#endif

    // do something
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t3bUw33DflfnDPU1)

Comment: Thank you, i tried this method too, if macros are allowed then its fine. :)

Comment: @Jessi Well, I think you said you are using `#ifdef`s to decide what 'variant' you are compiling, so just use those same `#ifdef`s here.

Comment: ja sure this works :)

Answer (score 2):

You could define a `std::tuple` based type to describe the accepted types and then use [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to enable instantiating a class from the template based on that.

Example (replace with your own types as needed):

```cpp
#include <tuple>

#if defined(VARIANT1)
using accepted_types = std::tuple <std::string, std::set<int>>;
#elif defined(VARIANT2)
using accepted_types = std::tuple <std::map<int,int>, std::vector<int>>;
#endif
```

Then we need a [`has_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25958302/7582247) type trait to check if one type is included in a `std::tuple` based type (see link to that answer for the full description):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
struct has_type;

template <typename T>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<>> : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<U, Ts...>> : has_type<T, std::tuple<Ts...>> {};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<T, Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T, class V>
static constexpr bool has_type_v = has_type<T, V>::value;
```

Then enable the template only for those types included in `accepted_types`:

```cpp
template <typename VarType,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<has_type_v<VarType, accepted_types>>>
class CMyClass {
    
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3qed9YdWq)

Comment: Thank you very much, i would try it  @Ted Lyngmo

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This answer requires C++20 and was posted before the information about the C++14 requirement was added to the question.

You could define a class template that inherits from `std::bool_constant`, `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` depending on the preprocessor definitions, possibly using specializations. This allows you to use the class template to create a concept for restricting the type arguments used with your class template.

```
template<class T, class ... Args>
inline constexpr bool IsAnyOf_v = (std::is_same_v<T, Args> || ...);

template<class T>
struct IsAllowed;

#ifdef VARIANT1

// you could provide everything in the definition...
template<class T>
struct IsAllowedType : std::bool_constant<IsAnyOf_v<T, int, char>> {};

#elif defined(VARIANT2)

// ...or provide a default and specialize for specific types
template<class T>
struct IsAllowedType : std::false_type {};
template<>
struct IsAllowedType<unsigned> : std::true_type {};

#else
#error unknown variant
#endif

template<class T>
concept AllowedType = IsAllowedType<T>::value;

...

template<AllowedType VarTypes>
class CMyClass
{
   // do something
};
```

Comment: Sorry for not editing the question when I got the answer to my question _"Are you using C++20?"_. OP answered _"C++14"_.