# Why is inheritance interfering with the compiler's ability to reason about the underlying type?

Tags: c++, tuples, template-meta-programming

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Tuple>
struct has_type;

template<typename T>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<>> : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<U, Ts...>> : has_type<T, std::tuple<Ts...>> {};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct has_type<T, std::tuple<T, Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename Tuple>
using tuple_contains_type = typename has_type<T, Tuple>::type;

using FooTuple = std::tuple<int, float, bool>;

struct Foo : FooTuple {
    using TupleType = FooTuple;
};

int main() {

    // this compiles
    if constexpr (tuple_contains_type<float, Foo::TupleType>::value) {
        // ...
    }

    // this does not
    if constexpr (tuple_contains_type<float, Foo>::value) {
        // ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The first case compiles, and the second case does not. The error I'm getting for the failing case is:

```
error C2794: 'type': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'has_type<float,Foo>'
note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'tuple_contains_type<float,Foo>' being compiled
error C2938: 'tuple_contains_type' : Failed to specialize alias template
error C2039: 'value': is not a member of '`global namespace''
error C2059: syntax error: ')'
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
```

Credit where it's due; the template for has_type and tuple_contains_type are from: [How do I find out if a tuple contains a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958259/how-do-i-find-out-if-a-tuple-contains-a-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there's no definition for `struct has_type<float, Foo>`.  Template instantiation does not invoke overload lookups and conversions.

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77246417/817643), template specialization and partial ordering doesn't do conversions or behave entirely like overload resolution would. If you want that behavior (to also consider unambiguous and accessible base classes as upholding the trait) you are going to need to introduce overloading and conversions yourself. Here's an excerpt from a [live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIACsAQAOqAqETgwe3r7%2BpClpjgIhYZEsMXGJtpj2hQxCBEzEBFk%2BfgF2mA4Z9Y0ExRHRsQntDU0tOSO9/aXlwwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbgReSfSH2CYaAIKb27uYB0cEAJ5JmAD6BMRMhAoXV1uZi2DB2Xn2hzcTgU30wrABN0BzDYCiSTFWeywDToBwA7FZETcCJgWGcmMTIa93sjHgAVUh7KmMVh007nDaXG4w4heBx7BBMBRfN6YQ4E25EklkinPEU0va0hHXbm8gj8wXC96Q%2Bl7GHoEAgE5nUVHAEcvYgXUEfUgKhiJSax4mfHOgAiYsBgOJpIMMuOcpZCoZTPlcmDAbYADpowr/hzASq%2BQKhUztQy9Qajey3GHY9HI2bsBb1SmRWmrTasya3LSFPnC3irLj3RtxV6pb7qyHAzru1GY7WlYm1cnHeWM4a2dWdbX6/HzZaJ98vJ8mY23R7Ccrl3y0gwANaNxkd8ldiN0i660L7iC0g5mABsczFeJbbclPtPkJ2goUQcZ575rGSpMF4RB7F4DAAO4/EkHwQEuU7anW0aXmgDAwnsABunjknQoqPnMewALSXohxrIXOlytu2n5%2Bj%2BCh/oq8Y3KB4GQTBTBwQh15EaR5rMeK3rSme1I9iBYGoBB0Gwbe5gPoyfGXlgOxMhAHGwR82oXBABBzM%2BNFbhuW7CZ2lLnv%2BfashRLHXF4e7AIyU4fOh2IYY6TyugBYlsJimDYrQBqjqmRw6iptBqVivyBSAGlcQh1oGuFWFiNqSGPjp%2BkGdgmZloZEp2Q5ewAGKoKgtJTp5FaZkhRyhAQDJULQqDkgyURlbQZrvtuPJ8qVUmWv1FXGuuNx7ONEFFcN9C0iKVVDbVbbNpuBX1XsLC/AwEBEc63UTXsAD0B2MggeB/mgpL4f8Y0TXgVB7OhMKYKoSTEHsunOa5m2llqRxNS1DUlWVBrTZgs2/TlIApd4mA7S6N37eNE5oGBTxuJC95mGijFgGAJjxG4DDmGYK37cZBX7UdJ1nZiqCYH%2BDCoAQgL7XdD0CE9L1vR9xoubI31jkcyACmQQOoBcBrQyucPiojE3I0saqQhjxN2nQuP44TxOkxN5MsxNxD%2BcsDB7BoK1uhwCyBRw8S8H4HBaKQqCcOjljWLqSwrE6wI8KQBCaJbCz7gkGj6Jwkh2wHTucLwCggKH/sO5bpBwLASDofwxAbaCmDkJQF1JPhxBx7ABdFwAkvqP5GFwuIaFwTtJLUcccMReqHK6phu5YZgaCR7zoIYjjIMRsTECQf7EQA6mItAkVPz3fEwycQGX9DEJXIDAFwGwBKgTcZC3bfWh3XdWD3ffEQPQ94CPY8T/Ps/z4vPwr2vsSb1hyBJHBWFcAAnB8TsMIPiqAABwPkbs3TgB0Mxn2sL3Q67ws5nTSFhTAxFDpTw2IHQI%2BAiDEDwPqBuBgjCb3gZYfQeAogl22lbTgttSD20ds7DgHgGCZ2zhiAAangTAUFYjvVwIQEg94NhcCIhsA6XBGGJy0PpUgCA4RYDiNtUgwd4ih2thHJhUdWGx3jn7AOCjrZmEjknaOHBeByNweg4uGQQCSCAA%3D) that accomplishes it:

```
namespace detail {

// Your has_type implementation goes here. Omitted for brevity

struct sink { template<typename T> sink(T&); };

template<class T, typename... Ts>
auto unwrap_(std::tuple<Ts...> const volatile&) -> std::tuple<Ts...>;
template<class T>
auto unwrap_(sink) -> T;
template<typename T>
auto unwrap(T& t) -> decltype(unwrap_<T>(t));

} 

template<typename T, typename Tuple>
using tuple_contains_type = typename detail::has_type<T, decltype(detail::unwrap(std::declval<Tuple&>()))>::type;
```

These helpers are there to check extract a `std::tuple<Ts...>` base from a derived class, and then run the verification on it. It works like this:

1. `unwrap` accepts any would-be argument, and just lets us pass both its deduced type as well as itself to the `unwrap_` overloads. Then it declares its return type to be whatever `unwrap_` resolves to.
2. The `unwrap_` overloads then have two ways to proceed: either convert the parameter to a `sink` object (always possible) or bind a `std::tuple<...>` reference to the parameter. Even though the `sink` overload is always viable, it involves a user-defined conversion, so it's ranked less favorably compared to a derived-to-base or direct reference binding sort of conversions. The two overloads declare the return type we'd want to see in both cases passed to our trait, and the overload resolution mechanism sorts it for us inside `decltype`.
3. `tuple_contains_type` is amended to `unwrap` a `Tuple` before checking membership, thus catching something like `Foo` now.

---

Some tangential comments and suggestions

1. I strongly suggest utilizing a namespace like `detail` for implementation details (as I did when working on your example). Otherwise you begin to pollute your own and potentially your client's namespaces pretty fast. It also serves as a "hand off" warning for other to not touch a traits implementation details (on account of those being subject to change any time).
2. It's not particularly ergonomic in my opinion to both make a trait both a predicate *and* potentially fail to compile when the condition isn't met for other reasons. It puts a burden on the users of a traits to essentially to the exact same checks in `unwrap` before even using the trait if they don't want a substitution failure. Consider just making the primary template be a `false` case.